# How can I set encoding on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, utf-8, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got a Java application running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk that is reading form an InputStream from a website and uploading something to my FTP. Some of the data, that is downloaded is in UTF-8, unfortunately the local encoding is ANSI_X3.4-1968. Is there some way of setting encoding? I have tried to specify it in the InputStream but that doesn't work:

```
...
URL url = new URL("my link");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
...
```

I have also tried to set it like this, doesn't work either:

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
```

Anyone can help? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got exactly same problem. You have to set `file.encoding=UTF-8` on java startup. For Elastic Beanstalk add a `Procfile` with something like:

```
web: java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -jar server-api-fat.jar
```

Comment: This was a life-saver. The following information may help others: With Elastic Beanstalk, you can choose between simply uploading a jar (in which case EB will run that jar) and uploading a zip file (a "source bundle") containing the jar, along with additional EB files (`.ebextensions` and `Procfile`). To set system properties, you need to do the latter, as that's the only way to include a Procfile.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set env variable.

Just go to Configuration -> Software -> Environment properties:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

Comment: On my Environment properties I only have the option to put in "key", "value" pairs for env variables. May I ask which part of your answer is the key and which is the value?

Comment: key: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS, value: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8